# Как поместить две бэкграунд-картинки на одну строчку

Tags: html, css

Проблема такая: две *background-картинки* располагаются не на одной строчке. Как это исправить?

```css
#img {
  background-position: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 348px;
  height: 286px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: url(el1.png) no-repeat;
}

#img1 {
  background-position: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 348px;
  height: 286px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: url(el2.png) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="img"></div>
<div id="img1"></div>
```

Нужно чтоб первая осталась на месте, в левой части экрана, а вторая была в правой части экрана.

Comment: у вас 2 раза свойство display описывается, так должно быть?

Comment: я убрал и ничего не изменилось, значит это что то другое...

Comment: [background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) вам в помощь

Comment: почему то без изменений(( можете проверить? я не знаю что уже убрать и что изменить

Comment: Так решается же это с помощью float!)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вместо `background` использовать обычные картинки, применив к ним разный `z-index`.

Answer (score 0):

Разгрузим CSS.

```css
.flex {
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#img,
#img1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div id="img"></div>
  <div id="img1"></div>
</div>
```